# Working with corresponding 3D numpy arrays in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I was wondering what is the best way to work with corresponding 3D array.  So I created 3 different numpy arrays, like this (this is just an example, the 3D array can be bigger), what I'm trying to do is replace some "sections" in each array of `arr` by the values in `arr2` and  `arr3`. For example in my code  I want to replace `arr[0, 2:]` (the row section with the ones) by the values in `arr2` and then the section `arr[2:, 1]` (the column section with the ones) by the values in `arr3` I was thinking in using `zip` but I'm having trouble, my code is the next

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
                 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
                 [0., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
                 [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.]],

                [[0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
                 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
                 [0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
                 [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.]]])

arr2 = np.array([[[43, 25, 21],
                  [28, 43, 28]],

                 [[38, 29, 46],
                  [48, 27, 33]]])

arr3 = np.array([[[43, 43, 45],
                  [28, 24, 38]],

                 [[32, 26, 30],
                  [40, 23, 20]]])

for i, j in zip(arr, arr2):
    for k in j:
        i[0, 2:] = k

print(i) 

#output
#[[ 0.  1. 48. 27. 33.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.] #The last array in arr with the last array in arr2
# [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.] #It does almost what I need, but not quite
# [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]]

#If I try using append like

aux = []

for i, j in zip(arr, arr2):
    for k in j:
        aux.append(i[0, 2:] = k)

#I get an error
#keyword can't be an expression
```

The problem is not only that, but also, I have 3 different arrays, so I don't want to create an unnecessary list after I finish replacing the row section and then use this list to replace the column section if there is a more simple way, my desired output is the next

```
 newarr =      [[[0.,  1., 43., 25., 21.],
                 [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                 [0., 43.,  0.,  1.,  0.], 
                 [0., 43.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
                 [0., 45.,  0.,  1.,  0.]],
                                                
                [[0.,  1., 28., 43., 28.],
                 [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                 [0., 28.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
                 [0., 24.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
                 [0., 38.,  0.,  1.,  0.]],

                [[0.,  1., 38., 29., 46.],
                 [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                 [0., 32.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
                 [0., 26.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
                 [0., 30.,  1.,  1.,  0.]],

                [[0.,  1., 48., 27., 33.],
                 [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                 [0., 40.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
                 [0., 23.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
                 [0., 20.,  1.,  1.,  0.]]]
```

So the first 2D array in `arr` duplicate itself and then replaces the values in the first 2D arrays of `arr2` and `arr3` and do the same for the second 2D array in `arr` and the second 2d arrays in `arr2` and `arr3`, if there is any way you can point me to the right direction I will be grateful, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way would be -

```
out = arr.repeat(2,axis=0)
out[:,0,2:] = arr2.reshape(-1,arr2.shape[2])
out[:,2:,1] = arr3.reshape(-1,arr3.shape[2])
```

Comment: And here I am, trying to reinvent the wheel, thank you so much! Clean and simple

Comment: @Divakar: I would suggest you add another line to help test the solution: `assert np.all(out == newarr)`.